# urlencode in twig path function

Tags: twig, symfony-2.0

I have this route:

```
_view_tag:
    pattern:  /topic/{tid}
    defaults: {_controller: "MyCoreBundle:ViewTag:index" }
```

And I want to show url like this: `example.com/topic/Web+development`. I use `href="topic/{{ topicname|url_encode() }}"`. It is works, but of course it is not proper way, so I change to `href="{{ path('_view_tag', {'tid': topicname|url_encode() } ) }}"`. But it is not showing `example.com/topic/Web+development`, it shows `example.com/topic/Web%2Bdevelopment`.

I also try this:

```
{% set _tid = topicname|url_encode() %}
<a href="{{ path('_view_tag', {'tid': _tid } ) }}" ...
```

But still not working

My question is, how to make it show `example.com/topic/Web+development` using twig path function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `path` function takes care of url-encoding for you. Your problem is that your space got encoded twice: first to a `+`, then that got converted to `%2b`. This will work:

```
path('_view_tag', { 'tid': topicname } )
```

Comment: I change to that, it now return `/topic/Web%20technology` ( i look at view source) not `/topic/Web+technology`. %20 shown as space in browser url (I use chrome). It is actually okay, but it will looks more comfortable if using + than space

Comment: The two are equal, on the server they both mean a space. If you really want to stick to `+`, you can use twig's `replace` filter on your urls, but I don't think it's worth the hassle.

Comment: Ah yes, replace filter. Final code looks like this `href="{{ path('_view_tag', {'tid': topicname } )|replace({'%20': '+'}) }}"`. Thanks Maerlyn for the help